# Git Bash for loop through files

Tags: bash, imagick

Okay, I am trying to loop through all images in a directory and do some compression on them. Here is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.jpeg; do 
    echo "Processing $f file..";
    magick convert -quality 85% $f $f
done
```

And here is the output from it:

```
 $ bash compress.sh Processing *.jpeg file.. convert: unable to open
 image '*.jpeg': Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3094.
 convert: no images defined `*.jpeg' @
 error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254.
```

The `$f` reference is actually the string "*.jpeg", which is definitely not correct.

Here is my folder structure.

[image: folder structure]

Comment: Either give the same input and output file `convert in.jpg ... out.jpg` or use `mogrify ... file.jpg`

Comment: You have a typo - `.jpg` versus `.jpeg`. Code is otherwise fine.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the filename should be the same, as I want to preserve the current names.

Comment: *"The $f reference is actually the string `*.jpeg`, which is definately not correct."* -- because there is no file that matches the pattern `*.jpeg`, the shell doesn't expand it; in consequence, it runs the loop once, with `*.jpeg` as the value of `$f`. It **is** correct from the shell's point of view. It expands the variables then splits the string in words and runs the loop with each word. No expanding => one word: `*.jpeg`.

Comment: @axiac this was the problem, once I moved the image to the root it worked! Great! Can you tell me how to do the same thing recursively for all image files?

Comment: You can use `find`.

Answer (score 1):

You should lookup files with appropriate filename mask (directory and extension). Also there should be skip path if bash can't expand filename:

```
#!/bin/bash

IMAGE_PATH=`dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`/nature
for f in $IMAGE_PATH/*.jpg $IMAGE_PATH/*.jpeg; do 
  echo -n "Processing $f file... ";
  if [ ! -r "$f" ]; then
    echo "skip!";
    continue;
  fi;
  magick convert -quality 85% "$f" "$f";
  echo "done.";
done
```

PS: `"$f"` (with quotes) used for files with spaces in their names.

**UPDATE:** Add using script directory.

Comment: I think that script execute directory differ from I meant. So I added workaround, see answer update.

Comment: My goal is to compress all images, not just the one located inside the nature/ folder.

Comment: Please add into your answer information about images location.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this, which does the job.

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./images -name '*.jpg' | while read FILE; do
    magick convert -quality 75% "$FILE" "$FILE"    
done
```